# How secured is my code?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and would love to hear how secure my code is (if it's secured at all?) and how could I improve it, my code can be found below:

```
<?php
include('header.php');
if (!$is_online) {
    redirect('index.php');
    exit;
}
?>

<div class="content">
<h2 class="title">Level</h2>

<?

$today_clicks = $db->QueryFetchArray("SELECT SUM(`today_clicks`) AS `clicks` FROM `user_clicks` WHERE `uid`='".$data['id']."'");

$pack['coins'] = 60;

$pack['level'] = 1;

if($data['level_reward_claimed']*100 <= ($today_clicks['clicks'])) {
    $db->Query("UPDATE `users` SET  `coins`=`coins`+'".$pack['coins']."' WHERE `id`='".$data['id']."'");
    $db->Query("UPDATE `users` SET  `level`=`level`+'".$pack['level']."' WHERE `id`='".$data['id']."'");
    $db->Query("UPDATE `users` SET  `level_reward_claimed`=`level_reward_claimed`+'".$pack['level']."' WHERE `id`='".$data['id']."'");
?>
    <div class="msg"><div class="success">100 points added and level increased!</div>
<?
}
else {?>
    <div class="msg"><div class="error">You need more clicks!</div></div>
<?}?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, well I was thinking of cheating the system by not having enough clicks but getting the reward.

Comment: I basically want to prevent my users from getting the reward without having the required clicks.

Comment: I don't like to be that guy, but I must warn you that SO is not discussion forum, it's Q&A board. "How secure" some code is, that's undoubtedly a discussion topic.

Comment: What I do see is the fact you query the database three times, where it could be done with only one query...

Comment: How is `$data` populated?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code reviewing. Visit http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the array `$data` is populated in header.php.   If it's user supplied parameters these queries are very insecure from sql injection.

Technically, if  `$data` is an array you manually populated yourself with the element `$data['id']` it's not insecure from an sql perspective--as long as no one ever sets  `$data['id']` to user provided data.

You should use prepared statements for all the data being assigned or used inside where parameters.

I recommend you also avoid trying to make your supplied data 'sql safe' by manually trying to quote and escape the data yourself.  Use prepared statements.  Period.  I can't tell what DB abstraction library you're using so I can't get anymore specific.

Comment: Maybe there is some magic sql-injection prevention in the `$db-Query`-method, but I doubt that....

Comment: @stUrb :) looks like just good old manual query constuction.

Comment: :) hence my "I doubt that " :)

Comment: @stUrb I mean bad old query constructions :)